# jQuery - Form Validation Plugin - One that works well?

Tags: jquery, css

Wait- please don't suggest the Validation plugin until reading.... I've looked into it..

I'm building a landing page with a signin and signup form.

Here's is what I want to happen:

Anytime a user clicks in a field, I want there to be an indication visually if the input is ok. and I want that to stick after they click to the next field.

I also don't want the user to be able to submit the form until everything is validated.

Yahoo!'s registration page does this best, take a look:
https://edit.yahoo.com/registration?.src=fpctx&.intl=us&.done=http://www.yahoo.com/

Any decent plugins out there? or is this a custom job?

thank you

Comment: Are you sure that can't be done with the validation plug-in? Check out this demo. http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/

Comment: I started a plugin similar to this but just haven't had time to work on it.  Feel free to do whatever you want with the code.  http://blog.greggbolinger.com/jqueryinstantvalidation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is both plug in and custom. I personally do not feel the initial indicator should be part of validation.

With that I would always recommend the [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), and extend that to include your indicators.